# Cocos2D CCButton setBackgroundColor not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I added the following code to the Cocos2D default template's IntroScene:

```
CCButton *playButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"Play" fontName:@"HelveticaNeue" fontSize:18.0f];
[playButton setBackgroundColor:[CCColor colorWithWhite:0.7f alpha:1.0f] forState:CCControlStateNormal];
[playButton setBackgroundColor:[CCColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:1.0f] forState:CCControlStateHighlighted];
playButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
playButton.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.35f);
playButton.zoomWhenHighlighted = NO;
playButton.preferredSize = CGSizeMake(222, 46);
[playButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onSpinningClicked:)];
[self addChild:playButton];
```

For some reason the button has no background color. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, using a custom font and trying to change the colour.  Has this been solved?

Comment: if you mean the background colour, it won't work. I created my own node which contains a cccolornode and a ccbutton on top to do it. you could also set the image of ccbutton to a 1x1px white image, then background colour will work, but that's ridiculous

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't set a color, only brightness (this is what "white" means in the context of CCColor).

Try using a color with this initializer:

```
CCColor* normalColor = [CCColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0f]
[playButton setBackgroundColor:normalColor forState:CCControlStateNormal];
```

This will make the button background red.

Comment: This works.  The problem may be the font as I recently experienced. The surrounding is was black and cannot change.  

Tip: Try other fonts to make sure this isn't the issue!